Computer cannot boot into OS, not sure what's causing the issue, recommendations for troubleshooting?
My main workstation that is usually left running 24/7 started to lag really bad.  I rebooted it, assuming it was a RAM leak.  It then refused to boot back into windows.  It booted into the BIOS fine, but even trying to boot to a USB stick would fail.  I ended up replacing the motherboard and that fixed the issue.  75 DAYS later, the computer was lagging, I rebooted, and I have the exact same issue.  I can boot into the BIOS just fine, but it freezes on boot.  I'm running windows 10 and even when I try to boot from a USB stick, it will freeze when trying to load the OS.  At some point I did run a memtest and the RAM all cleared.  I have no idea what could be causing this, it the system is just overheating and frying the MoBos or what's going on.  I can't seem to find similar cases online and I can't afford to be replacing $250 MoBos every couple of months.  The replacement motherboard was a different brand so I can't even blame a single manufacturer.  The latest motherboard was an MSI MAG B550 TOMAHAWK MAX WI-FI.  The issues seem to have started after I upgraded my GPU to an MSI Geforce RTX 4090.  The first MoBo died about 3 months later and this one after another 2.5 months.

A  RTX 4090 requires a beffy PSU (~750W minimum, I think). And it requires a good airflow.

MSI MPG A1000G 1000W PCI-E 5.0, 80+ Gold Power Supply w/ 12VHPWR PCIe v5.0 Cable.
Both GPU and CPU are liquid cooled in a Corsair 6500X Mid-Tower Dual Chamber PC Case

whats the CPU? have you tried replacing the PSU? do you use a UPS or line conditioner? have you checked the power from the wall (eg is it well wired w/ ground, and providing consistent 120v)? please describe what it does when it fails to boot from whatever source.

Something to try that's simple, no-cost, but long-shot: remake all electrical connections. That's what you did when you replaced the original mobo.

I presume if it was a power issue, the system wouldn't boot into the BIOS or it would either randomly power off or reboot.  I can stay within the BIOS indefinitely and the system stays powered on but freezes at the OS load screen.  The power supply works fine on other systems and other power supplies have the same issue.  I do have a UPS, but prior experience with a failed UPS tells me it would have friend either the PS or the MB significantly faster.
